# What is the relation between completeness and the closure relation?

Tags: eigenfunctions, complete-spaces

Why the [closure relation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ClosureRelation.html) is equivalent to the [completeness](http://latt.if.usp.br/scientific-pages/ftotcp/Text-I.html/node6.html) of a set of eigenfunctions: $\{\psi _k\}$ which is [complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%E2%80%93Liouville_theory):

> $\{\psi _k\}$ is a [complete](http://www.math.psu.edu/wysocki/M403/Notes403_8.pdf) basis $\iff \sum_k \psi^*(x) \psi(x') = \delta(x-x')$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\{\psi_k\}$ be a set of eigenfunctions that satisfies the closure relation. For a given function $f$ you want to be able to express it as a sum of the $\{\psi_k\}$.

Starting with the closure relation multiply by $f(x)$ and integrate with respect to $x$:

$$\int \sum_k f(x)\psi_k^*(x) \psi_k(x') dx= \int f(x) \delta(x-x')dx$$

Interchanging the integral and *finite* sum over $k$ we get:

$$ \sum_k \psi_k(x')\Bigg[\int f(x) \psi_k^*(x)dx\Bigg] = f(x')$$

The integral $\displaystyle\int f(x) \psi_k^*(x)dx$ is a constant $c_k$. $f$ is now expressed in terms of the basis $\{\psi_k\}$.